# structAppend vs Duplicate

Tags: struct, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am familiar with things like

```
if ( isDefined( 'URL'  ) ) structAppend( request.context, URL );
if ( isDefined( 'Form'  ) ) structAppend( request.context, Form );
```

Which is how FW/1 builds `rc.` I recently got handed some code that does this

```
_inputs = duplicate(url);
structAppend(_inputs, form);
```

What is `duplicate()` doing here? How is that different from `structAppend()`?

Comment: System scopes like `url` and `form` are assignment protected, meaning you cannot overwrite them like `url = {}` (nothing would happen at all). That could be the reason why the scope values are copied before working with them as shown in your second example.

Comment: It is also good to make a "deep" copy (independent) copy so changes do not affect the original scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if the original developer had come across issues when using the `StructCopy()` method and carried that over into their code for the `StructAppend()` method? I know that the `StructCopy()` method will copy nested structures *by reference* which can bite you. That is an example of when I use the `Duplicate()` method (to make a completely new copy of a structure).

I don't think that `StructAppend()` works that way though. Perhaps they wrote that code in an overabundance of caution. Obviously, this is just a guess.

[The `StructCopy()` method is documented to copy by reference](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structcopy.html).

> Copies a structure. Copies top-level keys, values, and arrays in the structure by value; copies nested structures by reference.

[Where as the `StructAppend()` method makes no mention of it](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structappend.html).

Comment: `StructAppend()` works the same way as `StructCopy()`: It copies top-level key-value-pairs and adds references to nested keys. It's pretty trippy when used with nested structures. Not recommended.